# Entity framework code first - create table and insert data from existing table into newly created one,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF code first and I want to create a new table and insert values from an existing table into it.

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserCulture",
                c => new
                {
                    UserCultureId = c.Int(false, true),
                    Id = c.Int(false),
                    IsSelected = c.Boolean(false),
                    Culture = c.String(false, 10),
                    UserLevel = c.Int(false),
                    CurrentScore = c.Int(false),
                    TimelinePercentage = c.String(false, 3),
                    NumberOfGamesPlayed = c.Int(false)

                })
                .PrimaryKey(k => k.UserCultureId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AskUser", k => k.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Id);

            Sql("INSERT INTO UserCulture(UserCultureId, Id, IsSelected, Culture, UserLevel, CurrentScore, TimelinePercentage, NumberOfGamesPlayed)" +
                "SELECT newid(), UserId, 1, CreatedCulture, UserLevel, CurrentScore, TimelinePercentage, NumberOfGamesPlayed FROM AskUser");

        }
```

When I ran this migration it created the table but it was empty. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I think because I am using a select statement I don't need VALUES. Ppp answer works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newid() is for uniqueidentifier?
Can you try removing that column in the insert statement?

```
Sql("INSERT INTO UserCulture(Id, IsSelected, Culture, UserLevel, CurrentScore, TimelinePercentage, NumberOfGamesPlayed)" +
                "SELECT UserId, 1, CreatedCulture, UserLevel, CurrentScore, TimelinePercentage, NumberOfGamesPlayed FROM AskUser");
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I think that newid() was something that I took from another example but it's not needed because of the increment seed of the Id.

Comment: yes, identity column is not needed in insert statement